# Adding CSS with JQuery to Multiple Classes

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to add

```
.km-android div.km-view {
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
```

when a specific condition is meet in javascript.

I've tried adding

```
$('.km-android, div.km-view').css('-webkit-box-direction', 'normal');       
$('.km-android, div.km-view').css('-webkit-flex-direction', 'column');
```

but that isn't working any suggestions would be great

Thanks

Comment: try `$('.km-android div.km-view')` - no `,`

Comment: I've tried that to that doesn't seem to work either.  Thanks

Comment: Why not `$('.some-element').addClass("my-css-class")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS you have `,` which doesn't appear in CSS. Try with:

```
$('.km-android div.km-view').css('-webkit-box-direction', 'normal');       
$('.km-android div.km-view').css('-webkit-flex-direction', 'column');
```

or even simplier:

```
$('.km-android div.km-view').css({
    '-webkit-box-direction': 'normal',
    '-webkit-flex-direction': 'column'
});
```

However `Nick R` has right - put this CSS in another class and just add this class to the element if met conditions, so:

```
.met-conditions {
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
```

and JS:

```
$('.km-android div.km-view').addClass('met-conditions');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('.km-android div.km-view').css({'-webkit-box-direction': 'normal','-webkit-flex-direction': 'column' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma from the jQuery selector. You can also use camel case properties:

```
$('.km-android div.km-view').css({
    webkitBoxDirection: 'normal',
    webkitFlexDirection: 'column'
});
```